# Terraform: Invalid 'for expression. Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression

Tags: terraform

```
locals {
  bucket_names = data.aws_s3_bucket.all.bucket_names

  bucket_prefixes = {
    for bucket_name in local.bucket_names : 
    bucket_name => format("%s/access-logs/",  bucket_name)
  }
}

parameters = [
  for bucket_name in local.bucket_names : {
    name           = "BucketName"
    resource_value = "RESOURCE_ID"
  },
  {
    name           = "TargetBucket"
    resource_value = "your-target-bucket-name"
  },
  {
    name           = "TargetPrefix"
    resource_value = local.bucket_prefixes[bucket_name]
  }
]
```

Error: Invalid 'for' expression.

I am trying to use a 'for' expression to iterate over local.bucket_names and create a list of parameter blocks for each bucket. The parameters block is part of an AWS config remediation resource. I want to add prefixes to the target buckets, and I want the names of each bucket to be used as the prefix.

```
parameters = [
  for bucket_name in local.bucket_names : {
    name           = "BucketName"
    resource_value = "RESOURCE_ID"
  }
]
```

Comment: The for expression is valid, what I am confused about is what you think will be in local.bucket_names. Since aws_s3_bucket data source has no attribute called `bucket_names`

Comment: I simplified the problem and tested the for loop by manually just setting bucket_names to a simple list `["foo", "bar"]` and it correctly output as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Chris. I missed the part of the TF configuration that would fetch bucket names. data "aws_s3_bucket" "all"

Comment: Wait, `for` expressions don't allow multiple elements. What should your `parameters` contain? Do you want a 2D list (then you're missing inner brackets)? Do you want 1D list (then still missing brackets, but also wrap whole construct with `flatten`)? Map? Something else?

Comment: Hey @STerliakov. Are you suggesting a parameters block like the below parameters = flatten([
    for bucket in data.aws_s3_buckets.all.buckets : [
      {
        name           = "BucketName"
        resource_value = "RESOURCE_ID"
      },
      {
        name           = "TargetPrefix"
        resource_value = bucket.id
      }
    ]
  ])

Comment: You still have not address the issue brought up by @ChrisDoyle ... https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket there is no attribute called `bucket_names` ... please provide a "working" sample

Comment: Probably - depends on what you want your `parameters` list to contain. Please show the usage site: you seem to refer to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/config_remediation_configuration, but it doesn't accept `parameters`, but singular `parameter` blocks, so you'll need something `dynamic` anyway. Please show how `parameters` list will be used.

Comment: @STerliakov are you able to reproduce this? ... how did you get pass the fact that there is no `bucket_names` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The "extra characters" that this error message is referring to are presumably the following:

```
,
  {
    name           = "TargetBucket"
    resource_value = "your-target-bucket-name"
  },
  {
    name           = "TargetPrefix"
    resource_value = local.bucket_prefixes[bucket_name]
  }
```

A `for` expression producing a tuple (as in this case) takes a single "element value" expression. The one you wrote for `parameters` has three expressions separated by commas, which is not meaningful in the Terraform language grammar.

If your goal is to generate more than one element per input element then you'll need to perform that in two steps:

- For each element in the input collection, produce a list of three objects. The result will therefore be a list of lists of objects.
- Use [`flatten`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) to transform that into a flat list of objects, by discarding the extra level of nesting.

For example:

```
parameters = tolist(flatten([
  for bucket_name in local.bucket_names : [
    {
      name           = "BucketName"
      resource_value = "RESOURCE_ID"
    },
    {
      name           = "TargetBucket"
      resource_value = "your-target-bucket-name"
    },
    {
      name           = "TargetPrefix"
      resource_value = local.bucket_prefixes[bucket_name]
    },
  ]
]))
```